# Errors when installing DPDK on Linux Alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, dpdk

I am trying to install `DPDK` on Alpine Linux. I am running Alpine Linux in the Docker. Here are the steps I am using:

1. `docker pull alpine`
2. `docker run -it alpine /bin/sh`
3. `wget https://git.dpdk.org/dpdk-stable/snapshot/dpdk-stable-16.11.8.tar.gz`
4. `tar -xzf dpdk-stable-16.11.8.tar.gz`
5. `cd dpdk-stable-16.11.8`
6. `apk add --no-cache make gcc libc-dev bsd-compat-headers linux-headers musl-dev`
7. `apk add numactl-dev --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted`
8. `make install T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc`

Installation fails with the following errors and warnings:

> make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'depdirs'.
>
> Configuration done
>
> == Build lib
>
> == Build lib/librte_compat
>
> == Build lib/librte_eal
>
> == Build lib/librte_eal/common
>
> == Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp
>
> == Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal
>
> CC eal_hugepage_info.o
>
> /dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_hugepage_info.c: In function 'clear_hugedir':
>
> /dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_hugepage_info.c:229:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'openat'; did you mean 'popen'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>      fd = openat(dir_fd, dirent->d_name, O_RDONLY);
>           ^~~~~~
>           popen
>
> /dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_hugepage_info.c:229:8: warning: nested extern declaration of 'openat' [-Wnested-externs]
>
> /dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_hugepage_info.c:229:39: error: 'O_RDONLY' undeclared (first use in this function)
>      fd = openat(dir_fd, dirent->d_name, O_RDONLY);
>                                          ^~~~~~~~
>   /dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_hugepage_info.c:229:39: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
>
> /dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_hugepage_info.c: In function 'eal_hugepage_info_init':
>
> /dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_hugepage_info.c:320:26: warning: implicit declaration of function 'open'; did you mean 'popen'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>      hpi->lock_descriptor = open(hpi->hugedir, O_RDONLY);
>                             ^~~~
>                             popen
>
> /dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_hugepage_info.c:320:26: warning: nested extern declaration of 'open' [-Wnested-externs]
>
> /dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_hugepage_info.c:320:45: error: 'O_RDONLY' undeclared (first use in this function)
>      hpi->lock_descriptor = open(hpi->hugedir, O_RDONLY);
>                                                ^~~~~~~~
>
> make[7]: *** [/dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/internal/rte.compile-pre.mk:140: eal_hugepage_info.o] Error 1
>
> make[6]: *** [/dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.subdir.mk:63: eal] Error 2
>
> make[5]: *** [/dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.subdir.mk:63: linuxapp] Error 2
>
> make[4]: *** [/dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.subdir.mk:63: librte_eal] Error 2
>
> make[3]: *** [/dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.sdkbuild.mk:80: lib] Error 2
>
> make[2]: *** [/dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:127: all] Error 2
>
> make[1]: *** [/dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.sdkinstall.mk:86: pre_install] Error 2
>
> make: *** [/dpdk/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:101: install] Error 2

**UPDATE 1**

I fixed some of the errors but now new errors appear.
Here are the updated steps:

1. `docker pull alpine`
2. `docker run -it alpine /bin/sh`
3. `wget https://git.dpdk.org/dpdk-stable/snapshot/dpdk-stable-16.11.8.tar.gz`
4. `tar -xzf dpdk-stable-16.11.8.tar.gz`
5. `cd dpdk-stable-16.11.8`
6. `apk add --no-cache make gcc libc-dev bsd-compat-headers linux-headers musl-dev`
7. `apk add numactl-dev --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted`
8. Add `#include <fcntl.h>` to `lib/librte_eal/common/include/rte_common.h`
9. Add `CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE` to `lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/Makefile`
10. `make install T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc`

Installation now fails with the following errors:

> make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'depdirs'.
>   Configuration done
>
> == Build lib
>
> == Build lib/librte_compat
>
> == Build lib/librte_eal
>
> == Build lib/librte_eal/common
>
> == Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp
>
> == Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal
>
> CC eal_vfio_mp_sync.o
>
> /dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_vfio_mp_sync.c: In function 'vfio_mp_sync_send_fd':
>
> /dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_vfio_mp_sync.c:75:17: error: 'struct cmsghdr' has no member named '__cmsg_data'
>       memcpy((chdr).__cmsg_data, &(fd), sizeof(fd));\
>                    ^
>
> /dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_vfio_mp_sync.c:187:2: note: in expansion of macro 'FD_TO_CMSGHDR'
>     FD_TO_CMSGHDR(fd, *chdr);
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_vfio_mp_sync.c: In function 'vfio_mp_sync_receive_fd':
>
> /dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_vfio_mp_sync.c:78:24: error: 'struct cmsghdr' has no member named '__cmsg_data'
>       memcpy(&(fd), (chdr).__cmsg_data, sizeof(fd))
>                           ^
>
> /dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_vfio_mp_sync.c:228:2: note: in expansion of macro 'CMSGHDR_TO_FD'
>     CMSGHDR_TO_FD(*chdr, fd);
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> make[7]: *** [/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/internal/rte.compile-pre.mk:140: eal_vfio_mp_sync.o] Error 1
>
> make[6]: *** [/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.subdir.mk:63: eal] Error 2
>
> make[5]: *** [/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.subdir.mk:63: linuxapp] Error 
>   2
>
> make[4]: *** [/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.subdir.mk:63: librte_eal] Error 2
>
> make[3]: *** [/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.sdkbuild.mk:80: lib] Error 2
>
> make[2]: *** [/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:127: all] Error 2
>
> make[1]: *** [/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.sdkinstall.mk:86: pre_install] Error 2
>
> make: *** [/dpdk-stable-16.11.8/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:101: install] Error 2

If you take a look at the `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h`, `struct cmsghdr` is defined as following:

```
/* Structure used for storage of ancillary data object information.  */
struct cmsghdr
{
    size_t cmsg_len;
    /* Length of data in cmsg_data plus length
       of cmsghdr structure.
       !! The type should be socklen_t but the
       definition of the kernel is incompatible
       with this.  */
    int cmsg_level;     /* Originating protocol.  */
    int cmsg_type;      /* Protocol specific type.  */
#if __glibc_c99_flexarr_available
    __extension__ unsigned char __cmsg_data __flexarr; /* Ancillary data.  */
#endif
};
```

What is `__glibc_c99_flexarr_available`? Can I somehow make this available?

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to use [this](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc) instead of `musl-dev` but the error remains the same.

Then as suggested, I installed `glibc` on my Alpine Linux to use it instead of `musl`. Follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777220/errors-when-installing-glibc-on-alpine-linux). Now I am getting errors like this:

> In file included from /dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal.c:48:0:
>
> /usr/include/limits.h:124:26: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
>
> # include_next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after some time and lots of workarounds I have managed to install DPDK on Alpine Linux i.e. on a Docker container running Alpine Linux.

Here is a Dockerfile I created (comments are inline):

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG DPDK_VER=16.11.8
ARG KERNEL_VER=4.9.4

RUN wget https://git.dpdk.org/dpdk-stable/snapshot/dpdk-stable-$DPDK_VER.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf dpdk-stable-$DPDK_VER.tar.gz && \
    \
    # Install Alpine packages
    apk add --no-cache make gcc linux-headers bsd-compat-headers binutils coreutils diffutils && \
    apk add --no-cache gettext bash grep sed texinfo perl util-linux vim build-base libexecinfo libexecinfo-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache abuild bc cmake ncurses-dev ca-certificates wget && \
    apk add numactl-dev --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted && \
    \
    # Enable usage of High Precision Timers
    sed -i "/\b\(CONFIG_RTE_LIBEAL_USE_HPET\|n\)\b/d" /dpdk-stable-$DPDK_VERSION/config/common_base && \
    sed -ie '/CONFIG_RTE_LOG_HISTORY=256/a CONFIG_RTE_LIBEAL_USE_HPET=y' /dpdk-stable-$DPDK_VERSION/config/common_base && \
    \
    # Add following lines / workarounds to header files 
    sed -ie '/int cmsg_type;/a unsigned char __cmsg_data;' /usr/include/bits/socket.h && \
    sed -i.old '1s;^;#include <fcntl.h>\n;' /dpdk-stable-$DPDK_VER/lib/librte_eal/common/include/rte_common.h && \
    sed -ie '/#define _VNIC_DEVCMD_H_/a typedef u32 u_int32_t;' /dpdk-stable-$DPDK_VER/drivers/net/enic/base/vnic_devcmd.h && \
    \
    # Prevent usage of the header files on /usr/include/fortify path by deleting them
    # Instead of them header files from /usr/include path will be used
    rm -rf /usr/include/fortify/* && \
    \
    # Add CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE to the following Makefiles
    cd /dpdk-stable-$DPDK_VER && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_ring/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_mempool/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_mbuf/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_timer/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_net/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_ether/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_cryptodev/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_vhost/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_hash/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_lpm/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_acl/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_ip_frag/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_sched/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_distributor/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_kni/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_port/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_table/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_pipeline/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' lib/librte_reorder/Makefile && \
    \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/af_packet/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/bonding/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/cxgbe/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/e1000/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/ena/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/enic/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/fm10k/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/i40e/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/ixgbe/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/bnxt/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/null/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/qede/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/ring/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/virtio/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/vmxnet3/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/net/vhost/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' drivers/crypto/null/Makefile && \
    \
    # Enable tests for compiling
    sed -ie '/EXECENV_LDLIBS  += -ldl/a EXECENV_LDLIBS  += -lexecinfo' mk/exec-env/linuxapp/rte.vars.mk && \
    sed -ie '/#include <string.h>/a #include <features.h>' lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_pci_uio.c && \
    sed -ie '/#define OFF_MAX/a static inline void outb_p (unsigned char __value, unsigned short int __port) { __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %b0,%w1\\noutb %%al,$0x80": :"a" (__value), "Nd" (__port)); }' lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_pci_uio.c && \
    sed -ie '/#define OFF_MAX/a static inline void outw_p (unsigned short int __value, unsigned short int __port) { __asm__ __volatile__ ("outw %w0,%w1\\noutb %%al,$0x80": :"a" (__value), "Nd" (__port)); }' lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_pci_uio.c && \
    sed -ie '/#define OFF_MAX/a static inline void outl_p (unsigned int __value, unsigned short int __port) { __asm__ __volatile__ ("outl %0,%w1\\noutb %%al,$0x80": :"a" (__value), "Nd" (__port)); }' lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_pci_uio.c && \
    # - test
    sed -ie '/LDLIBS += -lm/a LDLIBS += -lrte_pmd_ring -lrte_pmd_null' app/test/Makefile && \
    # - test-acl
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' app/test-acl/Makefile && \
    # - test-pipeline
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' app/test-pipeline/Makefile && \
    # - test-pmd
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' app/test-pmd/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/DEPDIRS-y += lib drivers/a LDLIBS += -lrte_pmd_ixgbe' app/test-pmd/Makefile && \
    sed -ie '/typedef uint16_t streamid_t/a typedef unsigned int uint;' app/test-pmd/testpmd.h && \
    # - proc_info
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' app/proc_info/Makefile && \
    # - pdump
    sed -ie '/CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS)/a CFLAGS += -D_GNU_SOURCE' app/pdump/Makefile && \
    cd / && \
    \
    # Install missing Alpine Linux kernel modules
    wget -nv -P /srv https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-$KERNEL_VER.tar.gz && \
    tar -C /srv -zxf /srv/linux-$KERNEL_VER.tar.gz && \
    cd /srv/linux-$KERNEL_VER && \
    make defconfig && \
    ([ ! -f /proc/1/root/proc/config.gz ] || zcat /proc/1/root/proc/config.gz > .config) && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USB=m' >> .config && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USB_HID=m' >> .config && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT=y' >> .config && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USB_COMMON=m' >> .config && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_HCD=y' >> .config && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USB_DEFAULT_PERSIST=y' >> .config && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USBIP_CORE=m' >> .config && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USBIP_VHCI_HCD=m' >> .config && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USBIP_VHCI_HC_PORTS=8' >> .config && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USBIP_VHCI_NR_HCS=1' >> .config && \
    echo 'CONFIG_USBIP_HOST=m' >> .config && \
    sed -i'.bak' '/hcd->amd_resume_bug/{s/^/\/\//;n;s/^/\/\//}' ./drivers/usb/core/hcd-pci.c && \
    make oldconfig && \
    make modules_prepare && \
    make modules && \
    make modules_install && \
    make clean && \
    cd / && \
    \
    # Install DPDK
    mkdir /dpdk-build && \
    cd dpdk-stable-$DPDK_VER && \
    make install T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc RTE_KERNELDIR=/srv/linux-$KERNEL_VER DESTDIR=/dpdk-build
```

I hope this will save someone's time :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems DPDK is not compatible to musl libc, so you'll probably have a very hard time fixing errors one by one. Having to manually add preprocessor defines and includes to CFLAGS seems like a bad sign.

The last error is such a libc incompatiblity:

> /dpdk-stable-16.11.8/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_vfio_mp_sync.c:78:24: error: 'struct cmsghdr' has no member named '__cmsg_data' memcpy(&(fd), (chdr).__cmsg_data, sizeof(fd))

In my glibc (Ubuntu 16.04), `cmsghdr` is defined as follows in `bits/socket.h`:

```
/* Structure used for storage of ancillary data object information.  */
struct cmsghdr
  {
    size_t cmsg_len;            /* Length of data in cmsg_data plus length
                                   of cmsghdr structure.
                                   !! The type should be socklen_t but the
                                   definition of the kernel is incompatible
                                   with this.  */
    int cmsg_level;             /* Originating protocol.  */
    int cmsg_type;              /* Protocol specific type.  */
#if (!defined __STRICT_ANSI__ && __GNUC__ >= 2) || __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
    __extension__ unsigned char __cmsg_data __flexarr; /* Ancillary data.  */
#endif
  };
```

Note the definition of `__cmsg_data` at the end.

In musl, `cmsghdr` is defined as:

```
struct cmsghdr {
        socklen_t cmsg_len;
        int __pad1;
        int cmsg_level;
        int cmsg_type;
};
```

Note the missing `__cmsg_data` field.

Comment: And if I use [this](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc) instead of `musl-dev`, it is also not working i.e. it shows the same error.

Comment: It may still pick the musl headers; the image should provide a compatible `glibc.so` to link against but I'm not sure about the glibc headers setup

Comment: But I definitely agree going for a `glibc` build is probably the best way forward

Comment: What do you suggest as the further steps?

Comment: First I would try figuring out what is the compatible glibc version, the one with the `__cmsg_data` definition, and how to get that on Alpine. I think the worst case is having to build and install glibc from source.

Comment: If you're not bound to Alpine, you could consider a different light base image (not as slim as Alpine though), perhaps one of the slim debian ones