# Errors when building glibc on Alpine Linux

Tags: docker, glibc, alpine-linux

I am trying to install `glibc` on Alpine Linux. I am running Alpine Linux in the Docker. Here are the steps I am using:

1. `docker pull alpine`
2. `docker run -it alpine /bin/sh`
3. `apk add --no-cache make gcc linux-headers bsd-compat-headers gawk bison binutils coreutils diffutils gettext bash grep sed texinfo perl`
4. `wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.28.tar.gz`
5. `tar -xzf glibc-2.28.tar.gz`
6. `cd glibc-2.28`
7. `mkdir glibc-build`
8. `cd glibc-build`
9. `../configure --prefix=/usr \
      --disable-profile --enable-add-ons \
      --libexecdir=/usr/bin --with-headers=/usr/include \
      --enable-static-pie`
10. `cat > /etc/ld.so.conf << "EOF"`

    ```
    # Begin /etc/ld.so.conf

    /usr/local/lib
    /opt/lib

    # End /etc/ld.so.conf
    EOF
    ```
11. `make`
12. `make install`

I am getting following error on **11th** step:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lssp_nonshared
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[2]: *** [Makefile:129: /glibc-2.28/glibc-build/elf/sotruss-lib.so] Error 1
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/glibc-2.28/elf'
>
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:258: elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/glibc-2.28'
>
> make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2

If I try to add `--disable-shared` flag than another errors occur.

The error could be solved by adding `libc-dev` with the following command: `apk add --no-cache libc-dev`. But this way I would have two C libraries but I need my application to use `glibc` specifically.

**UPDATE**

If I run `apk add --no-cache libc-dev`, `make` command passes successfully but `make install` fails with the following error:

> Execution of gcc failed!
>
> The script has found some problems with your installation!
>
> Please read the FAQ and the README file and check the following:
>
> - Did you change the gcc specs file (necessary after upgrading from
>     Linux libc5)?
> - Are there any symbolic links of the form libXXX.so to old libraries?
>
>   Links like libm.so -> libm.so.5 (where libm.so.5 is an old library) are wrong,
>
>   libm.so should point to the newly installed glibc file - and there should be
>
>   only one such link (check e.g. /lib and /usr/lib)
>
> You should restart this script from your build directory after you've
>   fixed all problems!
>
> Btw. the script doesn't work if you're installing GNU libc not as your
>   primary library!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, I changed few steps in order to build `glibc` on Alpine Linux.

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. `docker pull alpine`
2. `docker run -it alpine /bin/sh`
3. `wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.28.tar.gz`
4. `tar -xzf glibc-2.28.tar.gz`
5. `cd glibc-2.28`
6. `mkdir glibc-build`
7. `cd glibc-build`
8. `apk add --no-cache make gcc gawk bison linux-headers libc-dev`
9. `../configure --prefix=/usr \
       --disable-profile --enable-add-ons \
       --libexecdir=/usr/lib --with-headers=/usr/include \
       --without-cvs --enable-static-pie`
10. `cat > /etc/ld.so.conf << "EOF" # Begin /etc/ld.so.conf
        /usr/local/lib
        /opt/lib
        /usr/lib
        /usr/lib64
        /usr/libexec
        # End /etc/ld.so.conf
        EOF`
11. `make`
12. `make install`

I hope these steps will work for everybody else also.

Comment: Hi.I have this error when I run make. https://pastebin.com/ig3PRCjn

Answer (score 0):

Installing `musl-dev` should get you past that build error, too, so you'll be building glibc against musl.

The `musl-dev` package has its own `/usr/lib/libssp_nonshared.a`:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=libssp_nonshared.a&path=&name=musl-dev&branch=v3.8&repo=main&arch=x86_64

Comment: And how can I then force my application to use `glibc` instead of `musl`?

Comment: You should be able to do so by pointing the compiler to the glibc headers locations (using the `-I` / `-isystem` gcc options or similar), during build, and by pointing the linker/compiler driver to the correct library (using `rpath`) for linking,  using glibc's `ld` instead of the default musl `ld`

Comment: For `rpath`, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host
and particularily:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/7256341